# Gearman Client permission denied when called via browser

Tags: php, gearman

I'm attempting to convert a number of items in parallel with Gearman - I want multiple users to simultaneously hit a URL and have their item processed asynchronously in the background.

I've tried calling (from a browser) the following:

```
    $this->client = new GearmanClient();
    $this->client->addServer("127.0.0.1");

    $this->client->ping('Test');
```

Which results in:

> Warning: GearmanClient::ping(): flush(Permission denied) connect -> libgearman/connection.cc:696

Any idea what's causing the permission error ? Works fine if I call the code via the CLI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELinux was the problem:

> SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from name_connect access on the
>   tcp_socket

Solved with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```